# How to Transfer Files quickly from iOS device to iOS device using local network (like airdrop) >20Mb/s

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, file-transfer, airdrop

We are using MultipeerConnectivity frameworks MCSession method - (nullable NSProgress *)sendResourceAtURL:(NSURL *)resourceURL
withName:(NSString *)resourceName
toPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
withCompletionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSError * __nullable error))completionHandler
to send video file to remote device through peer to peer connection.

Returning with this - 1 min video transfers in about 30 secs. File size is 41.4Mb. Via air drop it takes under 2 secs to transfer.

Apps like ShareIt and others seem to have airdrop type speed.  We are hoping for something close to that speed.  Any suggestions on how to transfer more quickly? Does this require encoding/recoding or other approach?  Why is Airdrop 20x faster than what we are getting?

Comment: I don't see a question

Comment: Airdrop establishes a direct peer-to-peer wifi connection between the devices. It isn't, therefore, dependent on the speed of the local wifi. Multipeer connectivity can use peer-to-peer wifi but there doesn't seem to be any way to force this. How close are the devices? Are they in the same wifi? Have you tried the stream interface?

Comment: We are using peer-to-peer over wifi.  Devices are next to each other.  Works well for real-time streaming - over 30 fps.  Then try to transfer video file.  Other apps can do at Airdrop speed, which is 20x faster.  Someone suggested socket programming is source, plus maybe an encode and decode?